# When using glVertexAttribPointer, what index should I use for the gl_Normal attribute?

Tags: c++, opengl

I buffer normal data to a VBO, then point to it using glVertexAttribPointer:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(<INDEX?>, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
```

However, what value should I use for the first parameter, the index, if I wish the data to be bound to the gl_Normal attribute in the shaders?

I am using an NVidia card, and I read here https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/attributes.php that gl_Normal is always at index 2 for these types of cards. But how do I know that gl_Normal is at this index for other cards?

Additionally, using an index of 2 doesn't seem to be working, and the gl_Normal data in the shader is all (0,0,0).

I am aware of glGetAttribLocation and glBindAttribLocation, however the documentation specifically says the function will throw an error if attempted with one of the built in vertex attributes that begin with 'gl_'.

EDIT:
Using OpenGL 3.0 with GLSL 130.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. When using the core profile and VAOs, none of the fixed-function vertex attributes exist.

Define your own vertex attribute for normals in your shader:

```
in vec3 myVertexNormal;
```

Get the attribute location (or [bind it to a location of your choice](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml)):

```
normalsLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, "myVertexNormal");
```

Then use `glVertexAttribPointer` with the location:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(normalsLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
```

In the core profile, you must also do this for positions, texture coordinates, etc. as well. OpenGL doesn't actually care what the data is, as long as your vertex shader assigns something to `gl_Position` and your fragment shader assigns something to its output(s).

If you insist on using the deprecated fixed-function attributes and `gl_Normal`, use `glNormalPointer` instead.

Comment: Hey. I'm using glsl 130, I probably should have mentioned, and all the 'in' and 'out' keywords don't exist (My bad!) Is it still a similar process?

Comment: @ipe369 Replace `in` with `attribute` in the vertex shader.

Comment: @ipe369: "*Hey. I'm using glsl 130, I probably should have mentioned, and all the 'in' and 'out' keywords don't exist*" They do exist in 1.30. They were *introduced* in 1.30. It's 1.20 (the GLSL version used by GL 2.1) where they don't exist.

Comment: Really? So what on earth is the difference between 1.3 and 3.3?